# Fast find sublist in a list procedure (for packed arrays of integers)

Tags: performance-tuning

I want to find a first position of `sublist` inside a `list`, where both lists are packed arrays of integers.
A typical `list` has millions of elements, while `sublist` has just a few elements.
The question is: how to do this efficiently?

Built in function `SequencePosition` unpacks the arrays (even more than once) and is therefore very slow:

```
On["Packing"]

list = Reverse[Range[10^7]];
sublist = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

RepeatedTiming[SequencePosition[list, sublist]]
```

> {1.0, {{9999996, 10000000}}}

It takes about one second, but I expect that a good string search algorithm should run much faster.
It is clear that `SequencePosition` is too general for this task, because it also accepts patterns instead of `sublist`.

After some research I found that `SequencePosition` calls undocumented built-in function `` GroupTheory`Tools`SublistPosition ``,
but if I call it directly, I get very modest performance improvement and arrays are still getting unpacked:

```
RepeatedTiming[GroupTheory`Tools`SublistPosition[list, sublist, Infinity, True, True]]
```

> {0.68, {{9999996, 10000000}}}

Is there an efficient procedure to find the first position of `sublist` inside a `list` without unpacking?

Comment: Have a look at the `seqposC` function from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8364804/a-fast-implementation-in-mathematica-for-position2d/8367453#8367453). My measurements show that it is about 20 - 25x faster (requires a C compiler).