# What are the (potential) uses of those utility functions in the context GroupTheory`Tools`?

Tags: undocumented, built-in-symbols

[This old answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/103004) *briefly* described the usages of

- `` GroupTheory`Tools`Multisets ``,
- `` GroupTheory`Tools`MultiSubsets ``,
- `` GroupTheory`Tools`PartitionRagged ``,
- `` GroupTheory`Tools`IntegerPartitionCounts ``, and
- `` GroupTheory`Tools`ConsecutiveReplace ``.

However,

```
In[1]:= ?? "GroupTheory`Tools`*"

Out[1]= GroupTheory`Tools`ConsecutiveReplace   GroupTheory`Tools`IntegerPartitionCounts   GroupTheory`Tools`PartitionRagged

        GroupTheory`Tools`GeneralizedTuples    GroupTheory`Tools`Multisets                GroupTheory`Tools`SublistPosition

        GroupTheory`Tools`IntegerDecompose     GroupTheory`Tools`MultiSubsets
```

So what do `` GroupTheory`Tools`GeneralizedTuples ``, `` GroupTheory`Tools`SublistPosition ``, and `` GroupTheory`Tools`IntegerDecompose `` do internally?
`` GroupTheory`Tools`IntegerDecompose `` appears to do the same thing as `` System`NumberDecompose `` except that it only works on explicit non-negative numbers.
`` GroupTheory`Tools`SublistPosition `` was mentioned in [this old question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/145000), but in accordance with

```
In[2]:= GroupTheory`Tools`SublistPosition[]

GroupTheory`Tools`SublistPosition::argb: GroupTheory`Tools`SublistPosition called with 0 arguments; between 2 and 5 arguments are expected.
```

there are at least four forms (2 parameters, 3 parameters, 4 parameters, and 5 parameters) to call it in fact! (Any **thorough** interpretations?)
Last but not least, what is the correct syntax to invoke `` GroupTheory`Tools`GeneralizedTuples `` (which seems to differ from Python's `tuple` as well)???